# Evaluate indefinite integral $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt {(x-a)(b-x)}}dx $ using given substitution

Tags: integration

I have to evaluate the integral below using $x=a+(b-a) \sin^2(u)$ $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt {(x-a)(b-x)}}dx $$

I substituted $x$ and $\frac{dx}{du}=2(b-a)\sin(u)\cos(u) $ and then made the substitution $y=\sin(u) $ and$\frac{dy}{du}=\cos(u) $ and ended up with

$$\int\frac{(b-a)y}{\sqrt{((b-a)y^2)(b-(a+(b-a)y^2))}}dy$$

Am I going about this question correctly, and if so where do I go from here or if this is not right, how do I go about answering this question?

Comment: You seem to have been asked for $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}dx $$ not for $$\int \frac{1}{(x-a)(b-x)}dx $$ The change of variable $$x=a+(b-a) \sin^2(u)$$ is absurd for the latter and classical for the former. In any case, no change of variable $$y=\sin u$$ is needed afterwards.

Comment: Title as well, please... Now, ergarding the question: what happens if you forget the useless change of variable $y=\sin u$ and simplify as much as possible the $u$-integral?

Comment: $$a<x<b$$
$$x=a \cos ^2 u+ b \sin^2 u = a(1-y)+ by$$
Forget $u$, plug in , simplify, take it to next ...
 $$\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt {y(1-y)}}$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you make the change: 
$$\begin{align}x=a+(b-a) \sin^2(u) & \Rightarrow dx=2(b-a)\sin(u)\cos(x)du, \\
x=a+(b-a) \sin^2(u) & \Rightarrow x-a=(b-a)\sin^2(a) \\
x=a+(b-a) \sin^2(u) & = a+(b-a)(1-\cos^2(x))=b-(b-a)\cos^2(x) \Rightarrow \\
& \Rightarrow b-x=(b-a)\cos^2(x) \end{align}$$
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}dx=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(b-a)\sin^2(u)(b-a)\cos^2(u)}}\cdot 2(b-a)\sin(u)\cos(u)du=$$
$$\int 2du=2u+C.$$
Now, to go back to $x$, note:
$$x-a=(b-a) \sin^2(u) \Rightarrow u=\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{x-a}{b-a}}}$$
Hence:
$$2u+C=2\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{x-a}{b-a}}}+C.$$

P.S. The original problem was different, so the solution is updated.

Comment: @randb, please, check the updated solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was just wondering how $b-(b-a)\cos^2(x)=a+(b-a)(1-\cos^2(x))$

Comment: from the right side: $a+(b-a)\cdot 1 -(b-a)\cos^2(x)=b-(b-a)\cos^2(x)$

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are entering in a loop.

As you wrote $$x=a+(b-a) \sin ^2(u)\implies dx=2 (b-a) \sin (u) \cos (u)\,du$$ So
$$\int \frac{dx}{(x-a)(b-x)}=\frac{2 }{a-b}\int\csc (u) \sec (u)\,du$$ where the integrand looks like the logarithm of some trigonometric function.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Expliciting the "logarithm of some trigonometric function" you mention at the end shows that the suggested change of variable is absurd for the integral in the question, hence that there is most probably a typo in the question.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{1}{(x-a)(b-x)}dx $$
$$x=a+(b-a) \sin^2(u)$$
$$\frac{dx}{du}=2(b-a)\sin(u)\cos(u)$$
thus $$dx=2(b-a)\sin(u)\cos(u){du}$$

put this into integral
$$\int \frac{1}{(x-a)(b-x)}2(b-a)\sin(u)\cos(u){du} $$

now what is $\hspace{4pt}$ $x-a$  $$x-a=(b-a) \sin^2(u)$$
put this into integral
now your integral becomes.

$$\int \frac{1}{(b-a) \sin^2(u)(b-x)}2(b-a)\sin(u)\cos(u){du} $$

now what is $\hspace{4pt} b-x$ 
$$b-x=(b-a) \cos^2(u)$$

now your integral becomes.
$$\int \frac{1}{(b-a) \sin^2(u)(b-a) \cos^2(u)}2(b-a)\sin(u)\cos(u){du} $$

$$\frac{2}{b-a}\int \frac{1}{\sin{u}\cos{u}}du=\frac{2}{b-a} [\log(\sin(u)) - \log(cos(u))]+c $$

hope it helps

Comment: ...Which shows that the suggested change of variable is absurd for the integral in the question, hence that there is most probably a typo in the question.